# genfromtxt returning NaN rows

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am trying to read a csv file with numpy and I have the following code

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
data = genfromtxt(open('errerr.csv', "r"), names=True, delimiter=',')
```

and the following comes out

```
  (nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan),
       (nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan),
       (nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)], 
      dtype=[('name', '<f8'), ('severity', '<f8'), ('Message', '<f8'), ('AppDomainName', '<f8'), ('ProcessName', '<f8'), ('clientid', '<f8'), ('type', '<f8')])
```

dtype looks fine

and just to prove I'm not going crazy I tried this code

```
import csv
f = open('errors.csv', 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f)
data = [] 
for r in reader: 
    data.append(r)
f.close()
```

which works great, but im trying to figure out whats the deal with genfromtxt

here is a sample from the csv

```
name,severity,Message,AppDomainName,ProcessName,clientid,type
 Strings strings,Error,")  Thread Name:  Extended Properties:",SunDSrvc.exe,C:\Program Files\\SunDSrvc.exe,5DAA9377 ,Client
 Strings strings,Error,")  Thread Name:  Extended Properties:",SunDSrvc.exe,C:\Program Files\\SunDSrvc.exe,5DAA9377 ,Client
 Strings strings,Error,")  Thread Name:  Extended Properties:",SunDSrvc.exe,C:\Program Files\\SunDSrvc.exe,5DAA9377 ,Client
```

Comment: Note that if you're processing text data like this [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) would probably be a better choice than bare numpy; `pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv")` would have worked out of the box.

Comment: I'll be doing some other things with numpy, so id rather stick to one framework if possible

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `dtype` isn't fine.  It's specifying `'<f8'`, a float, for each of the fields.  You want strings.  Try `dtype=None`:

```
 np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=',',names=True,dtype=None)
```

which produces:

```
array([ ('Strings strings', 'Error', '")  Thread Name:  Extended Properties:"', 'SunDSrvc.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\SunDSrvc.exe', '5DAA9377 ', 'Client'),
       ('Strings strings', 'Error', '")  Thread Name:  Extended Properties:"', 'SunDSrvc.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\SunDSrvc.exe', '5DAA9377 ', 'Client'),
       ('Strings strings', 'Error', '")  Thread Name:  Extended Properties:"', 'SunDSrvc.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\SunDSrvc.exe', '5DAA9377 ', 'Client')], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S15'), ('severity', 'S5'), ('Message', 'S39'), ('AppDomainName', 'S12'), ('ProcessName', 'S29'), ('clientid', 'S9'), ('type', 'S6')])
```

(I have removed extraneous stuff about delimiters within quotes)

Comment: That '")...' was messing me up.  I'll remove the stuff about extra delimiters.

Comment: That did the trick. I had that set at some point but had other problems while cleaning up the data that led me astray. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You should also add `encoding=None` to avoid having the Deprecated Warning:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying
>   the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for
>   the system default.

Your line should be like:

```
np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',', names=True, dtype=None, encoding=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem reading data saved in csv format from Excel. It drove me nuts for a few hours until I found this. In Excel the first csv format on the save menu is the UTF-8 with BOM format - This produces produces a nan error in the first cell. If you save the file using other csv formats on the menu such as:
CSV(Comma delimited),CSV(Macintosh),CSV(MS-DOS), the genfromtxt function works without nan errors.