# Numpy array while importing from CSV

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a problem and I don't know how to handle it.

I have CSV file like this:

```
0.3,36.22683698,-115.0466482,1836.255238,0,0,0.2105903662,0.6848089322,41.15086807,2016/3/26,4:35:51
0.6,36.22683698,-115.0466482,1836.255238,0,0,0.2105903662,0.6848089322,41.15086807,2016/3/26,4:35:51
0.9,36.22683698,-115.0466482,1836.255238,0,0,0.2105903662,0.6848089322,41.15086807,2016/3/26,4:35:51
```

As you can see, first I have 9 float values and then 2 other which I would like load as string. Delimiter = ,

When I use:

```
load = np.genfromtxt(str(path), delimiter=',')
print load[0,4]
```

it prints value from row 0, column 4 and it works. Data is loaded properly. But there is a problem, because last 2 values are `nan`

```
print load[0,10]
>>nan
```

When I change my code into this:

```
load = np.genfromtxt(str(path), delimiter=',',dtype=None)
```

I get error:

> print load[0,4]
>   IndexError: too many indices for array

So everything works unless I add `dtype=None`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The are lots of questions about `genfromtxt` producing a 1d array.  Posters don't realize it has a compound `dtype`.  Read about `structured` arrays.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35699886/901925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create numpy array with several `dtype`. You have to import your csv with `dtype=str`

```
import numpy as np
load = np.genfromtxt(str(path), delimiter=',',dtype=str)
```

With `dtype=None` it creates a numpy array with shape `(3,)`. So you can't call `load[0, 4]`.

Each entry is a tuple with your data. Because tuples can contain several types.

maybe for your purpose you have to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
load = pd.read_csv(str(path), header=None)
```

the output is the following:

> ```
> 0          1           2            3   4   5        6         7   \
> ```
>
> 0  0.3  36.226837 -115.046648  1836.255238   0   0  0.21059  0.684809
>   1  0.6  36.226837 -115.046648  1836.255238   0   0  0.21059  0.684809
>   2  0.9  36.226837 -115.046648  1836.255238   0   0  0.21059  0.684809
>
> ```
>      8          9        10
> ```
>
> 0  41.150868  2016/3/26  4:35:51
>   1  41.150868  2016/3/26  4:35:51
>   2  41.150868  2016/3/26  4:35:51

each column has the proper `dtype` inferred by pandas

Comment: Hm, can I create two variables, load(with float values) and load2(with dtype=str) and then merge them? Cols 1-8 from load and 9-10 from load 2? And how could I do that?

Comment: With `dtype=None` you get the correct dtype, a mix of floats and strings, just like you'd get in `pandas`. But you have access the fields by name, not by column number. Look at the `load.dtype`.

Comment: with `dtype=None` you get an array with shape `(3,)` and not `(3, 11)` as expected. With pandas the shape of the dataframe is as expected.

Comment: What do you get when you convert the dataframe to array?

Comment: if you use `load.as_matrix()` you get an array with `dtype=object`

Comment: `dtype=object` lets each element be its own dtype.  It's what `pandas` uses when it can't assign a consistent dtype to each column.  Isn't there some sort of `types` or `dtypes` method that shows the `dtype` of each `dataframe` column?

Comment: if you look at `load.dtypes` there is a list of dtypes per column. But it uses `object` when array elements are `string`. For example `type(load[9][0])` is `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Applying an earlier `genfromtxt` answer to this case:

```
txt="""0.3,36.22683698,-115.0466482,1836.255238,0,0,0.2105903662,0.6848089322,41.15086807,2016/3/26,4:35:51
... ..."""
>>> load=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None,delimiter=',')
>>> load.shape
(3,)
>>> load.dtype
dtype([('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4'), ('f6', '<f8'), ('f7', '<f8'), ('f8', '<f8'), ('f9', 'S9'), ('f10', 'S7')])
```

The shape is 1d, but the `dtype` is compound, a mix of floats, ints and strings - 11 of them.

```
>>> load[0]
(0.3, 36.22683698, -115.0466482, 1836.255238, 0, 0, 0.2105903662, 0.6848089322, 41.15086807, '2016/3/26', '4:35:51')
>>> load['f0']
array([ 0.3,  0.6,  0.9])
```

'rows' or records are accessed by number, but 'columns' are now fields, and accessed by name (you can get the names from csv column headers as well, here they are generated automatically).

```
>>> load[0]['f4']
0
>>> load[0]['f3']
1836.255238
```

Individual elements are access by a combination of number and name.

A disadvantage of this structured array format is that the ability to do math across columns is limited.  A way around this is to group like columns into another layer of compounding.

With this data I can define 5 fields, a mix of float, int and string:

```
>>> dt=np.dtype('(4)float,(2)int,(3)float,S10,S10')
>>> dt
dtype([('f0', '<f8', (4,)), ('f1', '<i4', (2,)), ('f2', '<f8', (3,)), ('f3', 'S10'), ('f4', 'S10')])
>>> load=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=dt,delimiter=',')
```

Now the first field is a (3,4) array:

```
>>> load['f0']
array([[  3.00000000e-01,   3.62268370e+01,  -1.15046648e+02,
          1.83625524e+03],
       [  6.00000000e-01,   3.62268370e+01,  -1.15046648e+02,
          1.83625524e+03],
       [  9.00000000e-01,   3.62268370e+01,  -1.15046648e+02,
          1.83625524e+03]])
>>> load['f1']
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

`dt=np.dtype('(9)float,S10,S10')` also works since the 2 int columns can load as floats.

The last 2 columns could be loaded as `np.datetime64`, though the comma separating them might complicate the step.

These 9 numeric columns can be extracted from a `pandas` load into a `numpy` float array with:

```
pload.values[:,:9].astype(float)
pload.as_matrix(range(9))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add names=True in `np.genfromtext()` There is a similar question at [genfromtxt returning NaN rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066371/genfromtxt-returning-nan-rows)

Take a look over there